# #[automock] added only in test config but mock structure not recognized in integration test

Tags: rust, mocking, integration-testing, mockall

I've been playing with [mockall](https://docs.rs/mockall/latest/mockall) for a few days, it's working well with the crate added in the `dependencies` but now I'd like to move it to my `dev-dependencies`.

I've seen on the [GitHub Readme](https://github.com/asomers/mockall/blob/master/README.md) that we can do something like this

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
use mockall::{automock, mock, predicate::*};
#[cfg_attr(test, automock)]
trait MyTrait {
    fn foo(&self, x: u32) -> u32;
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn mytest() {
        let mut mock = MockMyTrait::new();
        mock.expect_foo()
            .with(eq(4))
            .times(1)
            .returning(|x| x + 1);
        assert_eq!(5, mock.foo(4));
    }
}
```

It's working well with a unit test as per the example but not in a separate integration test. I have an integration test inside a `tests` directory in which I'm trying to import my `MockMyTrait` struct created by the `#[automock]` attribute macro.

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
use automock_test::foo::MockMyTrait;
```

I get the autocomplete working in VS Code with rust-analyzer, it's actually detecting that my `MockMyTrait` exists but then I get an error telling me this is an `unresolved import`.

So is there a way to add `mockall` as a `dev-dependencies` only, use `automock` with the `test` config and reference our mock structure from an integration test?

I'd like to keep my application clean of all test-only dependencies.

Comment: Integration tests, i.e. those in a `tests` directory, behave like independent crates that use your main library. As a consequence the library itself is _not_ compiled in test mode for integration tests, and your `cfg_attr` disables `automock`.

Comment: You can add an `automock` feature to your library and enable this feature for integration tests. However activating the feature automatically when testing is a bit tricky, see: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/2911

Comment: @Jmb thanks for your comments. Indeed after more research I realized it's a limitation (a choice actually) of Rust. That's too bad. I'm not a fan of the workaround to use a `feature` instead. I think for the moment I'll leave `mockall` as a normal dependency in my project